# document is not defined in a Vue component imported to Nuxt when extract_css: false

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, vue-cli

I have built a Vue component using @vue/cli and tried importing it to Nuxt applications as a dependency. The component is built using `--target lib` and it compiles to `.umd.js` source.

When I use **vue.config.js** with the following setup:

```
module.exports = {
  css: { extract: false }
}
```

the component styles are included in the bundle and results in throwing the error `document is not defined` in the following line of bundle file

```
...
var styleElement = document.querySelector('style[' + ssrIdKe`
...
```

The component works completely fine if I set the extract value to **true**, but obviously that requires a manual import of the bundled CSS file ( which I want to avoid )

Is there any solution to get a custom component included inside Nuxt project with styles bundled?

Comment: How are you including you registering the Vue component in Nuxt?

Comment: in *package.json* I have added `"header": "*"` This component is then bootsrapped locally using `lerna bootstrap` monorepo tool, which creates a  symlink into node_modules folder from its local folder.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've got the exact same situation right now.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have abandoned the idea of shared libraries and instead import the files directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the server-side rendering. If you need to specify that you want to import a resource only on the client-side, you need to use the **process.client** variable.

Try this:

```
if (process.client) {
  var styleElement = document.querySelector('style[' + ssrIdKe`
}
```